# Ruby: How to replace values in a block of text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm quite new to ruby and so have no idea to to approach this...please be kind.

I have a config file that I need to read and replace 2 values...

The block I need to update is:

```
rails_root = File.expand_path('../..', __FILE__)
if %w(development test).include?(ENV['RAILS_ENV']) 
  worker_processes 2
else
  worker_processes 100
end
...snip...
```

I need to replace the values for "worker_processes" with new values...say 20 and 50 respectively...any help greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean "replace"? Are you saying you can't just open the file and type in the new values? When, why, and/or how would you like this replacement to work?

Comment: If it was a single file on a single host, sure.  But I want to automate this to update/edit 100's of hosts...

Comment: @user66771 you did not mention any automation or _"100's of hosts"_ in your question. It just says _"I have a config file"_. Please provide the relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby provides a few ways to manipulate data across multiple files. It sounds like you are thinking more along the lines of a FileIO approach, but for the sake of performance and the possibility of clutter, I would advise against that.

Since you're working within Rails, I would handle work_processes an a global hash.
Create `$work_processes = Hash.new` and have a set of keys that will be referenced in that file.

```
rails_root = File.expand_path('../..', __FILE__)
if %w(development test).include?(ENV['RAILS_ENV']) 
  $worker_processes[:dev_env] #=> 2
else
  $worker_processes[:other] #=> 100
end
...snip...
```

In this example, calling `work_processes[:dev_env]` in any file within the Rails project will return '2' and can be replaced with any number you want.

To learn more about the scope of global variables, check out the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/UsersGuide/rg/globalvars.html).

EDIT: I want to note that the use of global variables are frowned upon and can open you up to vulnerabilities. You can accomplish the same kind of effect using environment variables. `ENV['work_process_1']` and `ENV['work_process_2']`. You can find more information using these in [this blog post](http://blog.honeybadger.io/ruby-guide-environment-variables/).

Comment: Ah, I see and that will definitely be useful - thanks.  But in this case, there is an existing "bootstrap" script that can be run on the hosts in my environment to set various things (cron jobs,  configuring virtual hosts, etc) and I just want to add a section to read the existing config and modify the values.